# Transfer Data from One Table to Another or else Update the Data

Tags: mysql

Good Afternoon. I have two Tables and they are

Table: GeneralInventory

```
  WareHouseID | ItemCode | Qty
  Null          Null       Null
```

Note: as of now it is empty

and Table: Receiving

```
   RINo     |  ItemCode | ReceivedQty
    RI805ZFJ   FBMURG5WR   1.00
    RI467RGR   FBMURG5WR   1.00
```

As you can see this formats on Table are most likely you will see in Inventory System, My Table `GeneralInventory` is the Main Inventory where all Items that you will received will transfer here and that Table is `Receiving` as what you see in the table `Receiving` there 2 Data and they are.

[image]

Please be focused on the **RINo** field they are Different right? now here is what I will do and also my Question (I will convert my Question in Step by Step procedure of the Program)

1. The Program will Select 1(One) Data from Table `Receiving`
2. I will click a button named `Post` and the Program will do the Following

   -Check if the `ItemCode` of the Selected `RINo` already Exist in the Table                              `GeneralInventory` and If the `ItemCode`  is already in there then `ReceivedQty` of table `Receiving` and `Qty` of Table `GeneralInventory` will sum up or else add the Data.

I hope you get my point but if not I will show you further Example.

[image]

In General: If the Data Exist then Sum it Up or Else add the New Data.

I am using this Code.

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory (ItemCode, Qty)
SELECT RE.ItemCode, RE.ReceivedQty
FROM Receiving RE LEFT JOIN
     GeneralInventory GI
ON   GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty
WHERE RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'

UPDATE GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN receiving RE
    ON GI.ItemCode = RE.ItemCode AND GI.Qty = RE.ReceivedQty
SET GI.Qty = GI.Qty + RE.ReceivedQty RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
```

TY for future Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). For this it is necessary to have a unique index on `GeneralInventory.ItemCode`, so that duplicates can be detected!

Your statement would look like the following:

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory (ItemCode, Qty)
SELECT RE.ItemCode, RE.ReceivedQty
FROM Receiving RE
WHERE RE.RINo = 'Data of RINo'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
SET Qty = Qty + VALUES(Qty);
```

A quote from the above linked manual page to explain the `VALUES()` function:

> You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred.